# UPDATE ... OUTPUT (old value = new value)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can this be done in a single query?

```
UPDATE table SET value = @value, value2=@value2, value3=@value3 WHERE id=@id
OUTPUT (old.value = new.value)
```

I would like to know whether `value` has changed, because I have to send an amount of data back to the client only if it has really changed. I could always do it as two SQL queries, but that way I won't learn a thing... ;)

Comment: What do you expect to actually produce as output? Bearing in mind that SQL Server doesn't actually have a boolean data type (such that one could appear in a result set)

Comment: I expect an output on which I can check with a simple `if` whether the value had changed as an effect of the query. The type returned doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably can do this:

```
UPDATE table SET value = @value, value2=@value2, value3=@value3 WHERE id=@id
OUTPUT 
    CASE WHEN (deleted.value = inserted.value) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```